# Is this Google mail from gaia.bounces.google.com legit?

Tags: email, google, phishing

I've received the following suspicious mail in my Gmail inbox, about my password being exposed:

[image]

As you can see, it comes from *gaia.bounces.google.com* and is signed by *accounts.google.com*. But there are two weird things about it:

- It is written in Portuguese. I live in Spain (but near the border with Portugal, just in case that's relevant) and usually receive Google mail in spanish.
- The mentioned account is a @hotmail one I use as backup account, not the main Gmail one. It's been listed on *haveibeenpwned.com* time ago but I changed all my passwords a few months ago when I started using a password manager.

I cannot see any problem with the signature, and the links on the mail seem legit. I've checked the certificate on the linked website and read [this](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/180707).

Is this legit? Does Google warn about other non-Google accounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The email you've received is legit, it is signed with correct certificate of google.

However, you are not the first one to raise a red flag for this one, whole security industry specialised in social engineering is applauding google for great "phishing attempt".

To answer your question, yes google is checking databases of leaked credentials also for your recovery email address.

Chrome has now functionality for checking hashes of your passwords (to any account on any website you're logging into) with their database of leaked credentials. This is part of their safe browsing feature.

Comment: The thing is, I deleted all my passwords from Google, so theoretically they should have no hashes, right? I jumped to Firefox + Bitwarden almost a year ago. And, if they had, they would be hashes from old passwords. Also...why would they write the mail in a language different than mine?

Comment: This may be a geolocation mistake, you've said yourself that you're living close to the border. Google has had view of those in the past. My account (Polish gmail) was part of the breach of Spanish google server (I've received alert in English not Polish). This is not normal but it happens. You can mark my answers if you're satisfied with it.