# Critical security alert: someone knows your password

Tags: email, google, gmail

Mailed-by: gaia.bounces.google.com Sign.google.com 
Security: Standard encryption (TLC). So this is a legitimate email from Google.

- Will this email immediately be sent if someone (who isn’t supposed to) signs into the gmail account?
- Can Google send this email to warn you that someone else uses the same password?
- If someone really did sign into gmail with the password will Google immediately block their sign-in attempt and send this email as a warning?
- Does Google block someone who it doesn’t recognize and send this email immediately or does it take some time for Google to recognize that this wasn’t the owner of the email signing in?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is this Google mail from gaia.bounces.google.com legit?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/239297/is-this-google-mail-from-gaia-bounces-google-com-legit)

Comment: Hey guys first of all thanks for your responses, now i read the things you sent me and I’m a little confused.... so the thing is I received this mail on my main Gmail account, the one I use for everything basically... So what you guys are saying is that google figured out that my password is not safe? That its been used by allot of other people and therefore I should change it? Or is it possible someone managed to hack my gmail? Should I be worried that someone logged in my gmail? If someone does know my password and tries to log in, will google block that login attempt? I changed my password.

Comment: I did change my password immediately after the email but you know I'm still curious if I was hacked... Also what is a password dump? My knowledge of computers is pretty basic so that’s why I’m a little lost.....